# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptor.impl.jbossmodule13.ModuleDescriptorImpl

Tags: java, wildfly, microservices, wildfly-swarm

I'm starting with wildfly-swarm, and the demo app is showing this error to me:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptor.impl.jbossmodule13.ModuleDescriptorImpl
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    ... 46 more
```

It happens when i run the wildfly-swarm:run command, or even in a simple mvn package command.

There is any dependency missing?

PS: The pom.xml was generated by the site generator.

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>br.com.orlandoburli.exemplo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exemplo</artifactId>
  <name>WildFly Swarm Example</name>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>
    <version.wildfly.swarm>2017.3.3</version.wildfly.swarm>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
        <artifactId>bom-all</artifactId>
        <version>${version.wildfly.swarm}</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <build>
    <finalName>demo</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-swarm-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${version.wildfly.swarm}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>package</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Java EE 7 dependency -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
      <version>7.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- WildFly Swarm Fractions -->

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks for creating a JIRA for this. We will look into it as the generator should work fine